# Change the appearance of Excel Buttons

Tags: excel

Is there a way I can change the appearance of Excel buttons? I don't just mean the color and size but the over windows 97 look of the button. It'd be nice if I could use an image made in Photoshop for my button but I need it to still need the image to look like a button when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can place any Shape, or AutoShape or Picture on a worksheet and assign a macro to it that will run when the Shape is clicked.

Comment: what if I need a toggle button?

Comment: You could build the toggle functionality into the associated macro.